# Gaussmeter reads 0.01 mG, but I can still feel the effects of magentic fields

Tags: magnetic-fields

I moved into my apartment about 8 months ago and just after 2 to 3 days, I already felt the effects of magnetic fields. I realized after about 4 months, it's the magnetic fields, which cause me two things:

Constant hunger all day and getting tired a lot quicker by about 5pm (I think the draining of energy is fueling my hunger). I don't feel these effects when I'm outside.

I bought a gaussmeter and measured the magnetic fields within my apartment. I get a reading of 0.01 mG everywhere, except for one place: the circuit breaker in the dead center of my apartment. It reads 6 mG.

Before I go further, I also want to say that there is a high reading of radio fields on the Trifield meter I used. It was 1.7 mW/m^2.

My question is, if I feel the effects of magnetic fields (I'm 90% sure it's them), why do I get a reading of 0.01 mG all over my apartment?

**Note: I asked [this question](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/29232/21948) in the Medical Sciences Stackexchange.**

Comment: I can be outside all day and not feel anything. When I go into my apartment for a few hours, I get hungry and also tired.

Comment: If your keyboards read 0, why do you still think the effects are caused by their magnetic fields?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it sounds like a medical issue, not physics. It should be handled by a doctor. The thought that it is magnetic fields sounds like a mistake.

Answer (score 6):

> My question is, if I feel the effects of magnetic fields (I'm 90% sure it's them), why do I get a reading of 0.01 mG all over my apartment?

Your Gaussmeter seems to be operating in a relative mode so that it is showing differences from the normal ambient magnetic field. The normal magnetic field from the earth that all living beings experience naturally ranges from 250 mG to 650 mG. So 0.01 mG means that the magnetic field inside your apartment is the same as the normal ambient magnetic field to within less than a percent of a percent.

All biological creatures on Earth are exposed to this field from the moment they are conceived until they die. It is completely natural. There are no dangerous effects from it and humans do not even have any organs (including the brain) to sense this field. Whatever you are experiencing it is not the effects of magnetic fields in your apartment.

The only possible issue is if you calibrated your Gaussmeter inside your apartment. You should calibrate outside, well away from large steel buildings. But even then, it is highly unlikely to be a magnetic field issue. There are no deleterious effects of static magnetic fields up to 8 T, and humans can only even sense such large fields when they move their head (inner ears) rapidly in or out of them.

Comment: 8T sounds right, I have worked next to large fields at CERN and remember feeling it when moving.

Comment: Okay, it makes sense that human organs do not sense this field. But I'm wondering if magnetic fields have an affect on the brain in some way we do not know of. Maybe the magnetic fields have an ability to alter brain patterns and cause tiredness.  Could this be possible? And there's also the matter of USB keyboards. I could swear on my life when I sit in front of one, my focus is significantly affected. I instantly get this huge mental "fog" that just makes me want to push my keyboard out of the way.

Comment: @AdrianBartyczak even if there is such an effect, your measurements show negligible deviation from ambient field. With this, if the reason is magnetic fields, you should have the same symptoms everywhere. To more properly diagnose, you should check for what is _considerably_ different between the places where you feel different. As for USB keyboards, they are not much different from PS/2 or AT ones: the same operating voltage, same principle of operation, just a different protocol of communicating with the host machine.

Comment: @AdrianBartyczak of course, it is not possible to exclude unknown effects on the brain. However, if such effects exist at all then those effects are part of what we call “normal” since every brain on the planet is continually exposed to fields from 250 mG to 650 mG. You seem to be describing abnormal sensations, so it cannot be due to the magnetic normal magnetic field.

Comment: I have gone outside, calibrated my gaussmeter, and I still get 0.01 mG inside my apartment.

Comment: What's strange is that I feel these effects primarily when I'm in brick buildings. In the beginning of last year, I stayed in about 20 AirBnbs, and two of them were all brick buildings. And my apartment is an all brick building. And in all 3, I feel more drained and mental fog. I think its fields because brick contains them better. @Ruslan I feel considerably different when I'm near walls. I get some more thoughts all of a sudden (not bad ones though).

Comment: Bricks do not contain magnetic fields. Not sure where you picked up that idea, but it isn’t true. Given what you have described, you can rule out the magnetic fields. It is something else.

Comment: Sorry, I just thought that if brick blocks radio fields, it might have the same effect on magnetic fields, but it makes sense that it doesn't. It must be something else.

Comment: Looks like the World Health Organization has something to say about the effects of magnetic fields on the human body (see 3rd point). https://www.who.int/news-room/q-a-detail/radiation-electromagnetic-fields.

Comment: Nothing there is relevant to your case. We are talking about a static and uniform magnetic field. There is no induction involved.